# Keep getting a ValueError when dividing.

Tags: function, division

When I run this function, everything is well. I can put x to 90 and y to 9 and get z as 10. However, setting y to .9 won't work.

Please help.

```
def div():

    x = int(input('Number? '))
    y = int(input('Number? '))

    if x == 0 or y == 0:
        print('0')
    else:
        z = (x / y) * 1.0
        print(z)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you convert the input to an int value. The string '0.9' is not a literal so int('0.9') raise a ValueError exception.

If you want to handle float you need:

```
def div():

    x = float(input('Number? '))
    y = float(input('Number? '))

    if x == 0 or y == 0:
        print('0')
    else:
        z = (x / y) * 1.0
        print(z)
```